# How to get the elements from an array in PHP7?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the next code, what i want to do is to save and load the number of elements in the array, and show them in a function that i declared **show()** but after i declare the constructor foreach inside the function **show()** i have the next error

> Notice: Undefined variable: $COMPLETE_NAME

but, if i declare the same foreach in the function save, i get the correct result.

```
<?php

class Person{

    public $name;
    public $lastName;

    public function save($name, $lastName){

        $COMPLETE_NAME = array(
            "NAME" => $name,
            "LAST_NAME" => $lastName
        );
    }

    public function show(){
        foreach($COMPLETE_NAME as $list){
            echo $list;
        }
    }

}

$person = new Person();
$person->save("nameX", "last nameX");
$person->save("nameY", "last nameY");
$person->show();
?>
```

Comment: Same as all PHP versions, use: `$this->COMPLETE_NAME`

Comment: Scope issue [The Manual should help explain](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0):

Its a scoping issue and also you will loose the second name as you are overwriting your array as well

```
<?php

class Person{
    // define the property as an array
    public $names = [];


    public function save($name, $lastName){
        // use $this to access the property
        // also use [] as you call this more than once

        $this->names[] = ["name" => $name,"lastname" => $lastName];
    }

    public function show(){
        // foreach over outer array
        foreach($this->names as $name){
            // echo from the inner array
            echo $name['name'] . ' ' . $name['lastname'];
        }
    }

}

$person = new Person();
$person->save("nameX", "last nameX");
$person->save("nameY", "last nameY");
$person->show();
?>
```